# How to tidy up R code?

Tags: r, ide, tidy

I know that many programming languages have tools to tidy up programming code? Is there a way to tidy up R code or some tools that will do this (e.g. included in R IDE's?)?

Comment: For everyone else who thought he was using 'R' as an annoying shortcut for 'our': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language).  I have no idea, just thought I'd mention that :)

Comment: Emacs + [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) or (I guess) [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.org/) :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [formatR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formatR/index.html), which I found via [this blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/tools-to-tidy-up-r-code/).

Answer (score 2):

In RStudio, there is an option for this in the menu: Code > Reformat code. Default hotkey in Windows is Ctrl+Shift+A